SAS proc sql: select for each value the right interval
Suppose there is a list of clients and each client has different contracts that have a due date. For each client, I want to select the contract with the first following duedate after a given reference date.
For example:
Table contracts:



Client
Contract
Due_date




Anthony
Contract A1
2023/03/05


Anthony
Contract A2
2024/03/05


Anthony
Contract A3
2025/03/05


Bart
Contract B1
2024/05/01


Bart
Contract B2
2024/08/01


Bart
Contract B3
2024/11/01


Bart
Contract B4
2024/05/01


Carla
Contract C1
2023/10/03


Carla
Contract C2
2024/10/03



Today we are 2024/08/19, so I would want to select for each client 1 contract that will be due firstly after today.
So what I want is



Client
Contract




Anthony
Contract A3


Bart
Contract B3


Carla
Contract C2



What i would like to do is
proc sql;
create table DueContracts as (
select Client
       , contract 
from contracts
where due_date = min (due dates that are larger than *reference date*)
)
;quit;

The where clause is obviously pseude code, I don't know how to do this. I can do it for one seperate clients, but I don't know how to do it for all clients at once.

You are very close. You need to do pre-processing with where and post-processing with having. Think of it in two steps:

Get all due dates that are > the reference date (19AUG2024)
For each of those clients with due dates > 19AUG2024, filter to the date that is equal to the minimum of those dates

Here's how that looks:
proc sql;
    create table DueContracts as
        select Client, Contract 
        from contracts
        where due_date > '19AUG2024'd
        group by client
        having due_date = min(due_date)
    ;
quit;

Client  Contract
Anthony Contract A3
Bart    Contract B3
Carla   Contract C2


Why use SQL?  Assuming your dataset is sorted by CLIENT and DUE_DATE a simple data step with BY group processing will get what you want.
data want;
  set have ;
  by client due_date;
  where due_date > '19AUG2024'd;
  if first.client;
run;


You are probably right, but for now I can just learned how to use proc sql. In the future, I hope to learn to use SAS in a broader and better way :)
